What Happens to the Blue Space at the End of Death's End?
I’ve recently finished reading Death's End, the third book in the Remembrance of Earth's Past trilogy, and I’ve been thinking about the fate of the Blue Space. The ship plays a significant role in the exploration of 4-dimensional space and is a key part of humanity's efforts to navigate the cosmos. However, I’m a bit unclear about what exactly happens to it by the end of the novel.
Can anyone clarify what becomes of the Blue Space? Does it achieve its mission, or is it left unresolved? I'd love to hear others' interpretations of its fate.
Thanks!

Is this a book question? If so it's off-topic here on Movies:SE

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about a movie or TV series (at least not yet).  It'd be fine on [scifi.SE], though.

@MichaelSeifert - And thoroughly answerable too, I should note
